# Use array length to push items in an array

Tags: javascript

I have an items array with specific length depending on how many items in an order there are.
I have to calculate the packaging for it, for every 2 items I use the large box and the single item goes in a small box.

So if there are 5 items its 2 large boxes and 1 small box.
How do I do this using the array length? or any other way?

Comment: Yeah you're thinking on right way, give it a try, if you still stuck then post the code you've tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the modulo operator:

```
let numBigBoxes = 0;
let numSmallBoxes = 0;    

if (items.length === 1) {
    numSmallBoxes = 1;
} else if (items.length % 2 === 0) {
    numBigBoxes = items.length / 2;     
} else {
    numBigBoxes = (items.length - 1) / 2;
    numSmallBoxes = 1;
}
```

Comment: @Jaykch: if you hover over the down-vote arrow on any question, you'll see the reason for the down-votes. For instance, usually you're expected to show some evidence of effort in your question. You may have expended effort, but the question shows no concrete evidence for it whatsoever.